# Get environment variables in .scss file in reactjs application

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, environment-variables, media-queries

I have a scenario where I will be getting the background image URL through a CDN whose base path is set in the environment file. Since I can access the environment variable only in the `.js` file and not in `.scss`, defining the style in `.scss` isn't possible. I could use inline styles, but I would like to show/hide the background image based on device size through media query. But I cannot get that in `.js`.

So, is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can have several CSS files that you require in React depending on the environment variable. An example could be:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    require('./dev_only_styles.css');
}
```

Comment: Nice thought. So as moigonz said, you can show the background image using inline styles in js, and use css to show hide that image from css media queries.